# VLC Command Line Toggle Play

Tags: vlc

I'm currently using this command to trigger VLC to play an audio file using a piece of software:

```
-qt-start-minimized --play-and-exit --qt-notification=0 "D:\SFX\audiofile.mp3"
```

Is their anyway through VLC command line of stopping the specific instance of VLC that was playing? or VLC being able to detect if the specific audio file is already playing then stop the audio else play the audio file.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this parameter could help you achieve what you want :

```
--one-instance
```

Comment: My problem is that I may have 3 different audio files playing at once but I want to stop just one of them.